# Unable to access the internet in centOS from a static IP

Tags: linux, networking, centos, connection

I'm trying to setup a centOS server with a public static IP address but if I try and ping the router (192.168.1.1) I get "Network is unreachable", if I try and ping google.com I get "unknown host google.com"

This is the dump from ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr D4:9A:20:F8:9D:F8  
          inet addr:200.37.213.113  Bcast:200.37.213.113  Mask:255.255.255.248
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1178 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1014 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:292875 (286.0 KiB)  TX bytes:40593 (39.6 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:249 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:249 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:20076 (19.6 KiB)  TX bytes:20076 (19.6 KiB)
```

Dump from route:

```
Kernel IP routing table 
Destination     Gateway          Genmask           Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
200.37.213.112  *                255.255.255.248   U     0      0   0   eth0
link-local      *                255.255.0.0       U     1002   0   0   eth0
0.0.0.0         200.37.213.118   0.0.0.0           UG    0      0   0   eth0
```

Dump from /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1             localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1                   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
200.37.213.113        server.mypersonaldomain.com server
```

Dump from /etc/resolve.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Dump from /etc/sysconfig/network

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=server.mypersonaldomain.com
GATEWAY=200.37.213.118
```

Dump from /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

```
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="none"
IPADDR:="200.37.213.113"
NETMASK="255.255.255.248"
GATEWAY="200.37.213.118"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong here?

- Update - I'm able to ping 200.37.213.113 and receive a response, but not 200.37.213.118 or any other domain/IP
- Update - Still having troubles with this, does anyone else have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a default gateway which is demonstrated by your `route` "dump" so your server has no way of sending traffic to a destination that is not a specific match within your routing table.

**Dump from route:**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway    Genmask            Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
Your IP  *          255.255.255.248    U     0      0   0   eth0
link-local      *          255.255.0.0        U     1002   0   0   eth0
```

You can add a route to the outside world by setting a `GATEWAY` under your ifcfg-eth0 and bouncing the network service or eth0:

```
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="none"
IPADDR:="Your IP"
NETMASK="255.255.255.248"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
GATEWAY="Your Gateway IP"  <----
```

Comment: Thanks for the super-quick answer, I've updated the ifcfg-eth0 and added the gateway, restarted the eth0 and networking and still the same problem. Is there another route I need to add?

Comment: Can you please update your question with your updated `route` output and if you're able to ping your default gateway?

Comment: Done. It's placed a 0.0.0.0/Default route into the list, but hasn't appeared to fix the issue.

Comment: If you can't ping your default gateway you will remain without connectivity until you solve this issue. Is your server sitting on the same layer-2 segment as your gateway? Can you see ARP entries for these devices on the server or the device the server is connected? Can you tell us about your topology? (Also, while your attention to detail is great, I suggest you edit out all of the public IP address information in your post.)

Comment: Alright thanks for the advice. I'm relatively new to networking so I'm not entirely sure about half of what you've asked for unfortunately, however It's given me a direction to look into which is a great help in itself. Basically I've got a router running DDWRT, then the server connected directly to that. I'm able to setup the server and get network connectivity through DHCP and the networks dynamic IP, but I want to assign it one of the 10 static public IP's provided by my ISP. I hope that helps explain better. Also the IP's in the post are fictional, thanks for the consideration though.

Answer (score 1):

Your router ip is 192.168.1.1
but your host ip is 200.37.213.113.
Both your host and router are in two different network there's no way it can reach 200.37.213.118

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the GUI, you have to set up all the values not only in shell but also in the GUI manually.
Try to turn off the firewall (also services iptables & ip6tables), as well as selinux.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this video to the tee and it worked: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWSnpaZK_BI

You will need to know which one of your network interface is the active one, e.g. eth0, eth1 or ...

A note to VMware player users, even though the default gateway (setup by VMware player) is 192.168.38.1 and the name server is 192.168.38.2, use 192.168.38.2 as the GATEWAY AND nameserver in files shown in the above video, and everything will work.

Comment: It would be preferable if you condensed the relevant points of that video down in your answer, in case the video gets deleted or unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

**Add a default gateway**

```
# route add default gw 200.37.213.113 eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation. It was resolved by adding correct `search` domain and `nameserver` entries in `/etc/resolv.conf`.